# What's the specific verb for listening to/enjoying a concert?

Tags: vocabulary, verb

What's the verb specifically for listening to/enjoying a concert/music?

I think there is a (Hanja) based verb for listening to/enjoying a concert/music.
Unfortunately, dictionaries/translation tools are only giving me 듣다/즐기다.

(Also I think there is another verb for visual arts like movies/plays?)

---

**Update:**

I think I was thinking of 시청하다 (to watch) and 감상하다 (to appreciate).

- Any audio version of 시청하다?
- Can 감상하다 be used for audio things like music and concerts?

Comment: 관람하다 can be used for movies (at the theater) and plays. For the last two questions, my answers are "청취하다" and "감**상**하다 (*not* 감성하다) can." You should also note that 청취하다 is usually used for the radio, whereas 시청하다 is used for TV and videos (including movies on TV and YouTube videos).

Comment: 관람하다, as Klmo said, can be used for movies, plays, concerts, exhibitions, and others which are displayed/performed at some place. 관람하다 usually implies that one physically goes to that place, while other words he mentioned do not imply that. In other words, 관람하다 is not a good choice (but 감상하다 is) when, for example, one just watches them on TV.

Answer (score 1):

In 시청하다, 시 means 'watch' and 청 means 'listen'. So you can use 시청하다 for watching TV, videos, movies, etc. These things are watched and also listened.

As mentioned in the comment, you can use 청취하다 for only 'listening'. 라디오를 청취하다 works but 라디오를 시청하다 doesn't work, because radios cannot be watched. 영화를 시청하다 works but 영화를 청취하다 doesn't work, because movies can be not only listened, but also watched.

According to 표준국어대사전(standard Korean dictionary), 감상하다 means that 주로 예술 작품을 이해하여 즐기고 평가하다(appreciate, enjoy and evaluate mostly works of art). So you can use 감상하다 for audio things.